# How to dynamically loop through different arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

If I want to loop through both of these arrays:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'email' => string 'testr@example.com' (length=17)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => string 'Joe' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'lastName' => string 'Doe' (length=3)
```

and

```
array (size=2)
  'email' => string 'taylor@example.com' (length=18)
  'name' => string 'Jay' (length=3)
```

The reason I am showing both arrays is I am trying to write a function to handle both arrays. I understand how to loop through the second array as I have been using in my function:

```
foreach($inserts as $colName => $colValue)
{
  //...
}
```

However, its the first array that I am struggling with, how can I handle  looping through the first array while still supporting looping through the second array as my function could be passed both types of arrays that I showed above?

I did try and have a go with two foreach loops for the first array but I am wondering if there is a way where I can just have one loop to handle both types of arrays and if there is a way to detect the first type of array as I need to do something if the first type of array is passed in?

Comment: You want to use a single loop for both arrays?

Comment: If possible? Or a way to loop through the first array when detected?

Comment: array_map or array_reduce with callback function may be help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stick with the second case which  is simpler, and detect if you run
in the  first one.  If that's  the case, you  transform the  values. The
trick here is the usage of [`is_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php):

```
foreach ($inserts as $colName => $colValue) {
    if (is_array($colValue)) {
        # get first key
        $colName = array_shift(array_keys($colValue));
        # reassign value
        $colValue = $colValue($colName);
    }
    # proceed as normal ...
}
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that you might need some security measures, if you can't guarantee that the array will always have the same content format.

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate a little as to why it would be security issue?

Comment: Is your nested array case guaranteed to have at least one element? If not, the `array_keys` line will cause a problem. Just add a check if you need, I didn't add in the answer. But if you think it is worth checking for the format, please do :)

Comment: Yeah my array will always have at least one element, as I will have control over the array structure its just the data that is different. Sorry to bother you more but if I am correct 'array_shift(array_keys($colValue))' basically gets the first key from my first array example in my question, then 'array_shit' pops off the 0 in the array returned by 'array_keys(colValue)'?

Comment: @Erdss4 yes that's precisely what it does. You can also just access the array with `[0]` or use reset() and key(). Many ways of achieving this.